# SQL : a condition (IF-ELSE) in INSERT INTO

Tags: sql-server, insert, request

Is it possible ?

> ```
> INSERT INTO tblPeople (id, group, company) VALUES (1, 'myGroup', 
> IF($company = '') BEGIN 'no company' ELSE 'myCompany' END)
> ```

I would like test a value, an if the variable $company is empty, I would like write no company.

Comment: Have you tried doing the check before doing the insert?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: in my case, I can not do it before. I use SQL Server

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO tblPeople (id, group, company) 
select 1, 'myGroup', 
case 
  when @company is null or  @company = '' then 'no company' 
  else 'myCompany' 
END as  company
/*from tab --<-- optional*/
```

Comment: not working for me ? is this depends on mysql version ?

I have created a table like this 
"create table tutorials_tbl(
   id INT NOT NULL ,
   company VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
"

Answer (score 6):

Probably not, but

```
INSERT INTO tblPeople (id, [group], company) 
Select 1, 'myGroup', Case When @Company = '' then 'no company' Else 'my company' End
```

Should be a goer